# How to write on root window in x11?

Tags: c, x11, xlib, xserver

I've already read a lot of questions titled like this one, but none results in an answer that fits my needs.

I want to write some stuff on my root-window (in C) for displaying stuff like uptime as an example. The problem is: I want to have this as background *all the time*! 
There is one way to use a background image and draw onto this and set it as background, but thats ugly. Another way would be to write onto the rootwindow and refreshing it all the time, so if another window covers and uncovers my printed stuff, it will be refreshed in almost no time. But that isn't really an answer because energy/cputime is expensive.

kind regards.

Answer (score 4):

Just add expose event handler and do your code whenever ExposeNotify event is sent to you. 
Don't forget to set expose event input mask: `XSelectInput(display, root, ExposureMask)` so events are sent to your client (each window event mask is stored separately per client)